# Can Ligo tell a blackhole and neutron star of same mass throughout the inspiral?

Tags: black-holes, mass, astrophysics, neutron-stars, ligo

I am wondering what if a massive blackhole which is say thrice as massive as our Sun is gobbling up a neutron star also happens to be of the exact same mass, so in this scenario can Ligo be able to tell them apart without looking at the sky? Like for example is it 2 binary blackholes merger, 2 binary neutron stars or a blackhole consuming a neutron star of the same mass without looking for any kilonova, etc.

Comment: Also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/251198/gravitational-waves-from-neutron-star-neutron-star-merger